# How do you add liquidity with the Uniswap v3 SDK?

Tags: uniswap

Experimenting with the Uniswap v3 exchange. I'm trying to figure out how to add liquidity using the v3 SDK, does anyone have examples of how to do this?

Looking at the docs, it seems like [`NonFungiblePositionManager`](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/reference/classes/NonfungiblePositionManager) may be the method to call.

Can anyone confirm, and/or provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

The [uniswap v3 docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/) have some good examples:

- [Create a trade](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/creating-a-trade)
- [Add liquidity](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/liquidity/adding)
- There is also an example in the [uniswap sdk github repo](https://github.com/Uniswap/docs/blob/main/sdk-examples/AddAndRemoveLiquidity.tsx)

To my understanding, what all these examples actually leave out is the part of executing the trade by communicating with the blockchain via ethers.

But in the [ethers docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) you can find how to get a [signer](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/) (necessary part to access your wallet/address via ethers and authorize a transaction). The final step is then to interact with the [contract](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/) and do the transaction, and this is greatly simplified through the uniswap sdk, as their examples provide all the necessary parameters.

Comment: Add liquidity link is no longer working